# Slow Vagrant performance?

Tags: ant, phpunit, vagrant

I have a PHPUnit test suite ..

on my dual core laptop it takes 7 minutes to finish executing.. using a vagrant box (virtualbox provider)

```
~/project/module/ModuleName/tests:$ phpunit
PHPUnit 3.7.37 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from ~/project/module/ModuleName/tests/phpunit.xml.dist

..F..FFF..FFFFFF..FFFFF...FFFFFFFFF

Time: 6.82 minutes, Memory: 6.00Mb
```

Yet, on my virtual machine guest image running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS .. it's taking only a fraction of that.  Anyone have thoughts as to why?  **The only difference with the guest's execution is it's via an ant script and without Vagrant**

```
phpunit:
     [exec] PHPUnit 3.7.37 by Sebastian Bergmann.
     [exec]
     [exec] Configuration read from <~/tests/phpunit.xml.dist>
     [exec]
     [exec] .. [41;37mF [0m.. [41;37mF [0m [41;37mF [0m [41;37mF [0m.. [41;37mF [0m [41;37mF [0m [41;37mF [0m [41;37mF [0m [41;37mF [0m [41;37mF [0m.. [41;37mF [0m [41;37mF [0m [41;37mF [0m [41;37mF [0m [41;37mF [0m... [41;37mF [0m [41;37mF [0m [41;37mF [0m [41;37mF [0m [41;37mF [0m [41;37mF [0m [41;37mF [0m [41;37mF [0m [41;37mF [0m
     [exec]
     [exec] Time: 760 ms, Memory: 6.00Mb
     [exec]
     [exec] There were 24 failures:
     [exec]
```

Comment: Are you using a shared folder to hold the data? If so, shared folders mounted using vboxfs do *not* offer read caches which explains the lousy performance. Use NFS instead.

Comment: The entire project and any log files all occur underneath the shared Vagrant folder.. Ill lookup how to start using NFS thanks

Comment: I wrapped that info in my answer. I had this problem with my vagrant boxes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are storing the files you are using on a share between your Vagrant host and the VM, the reason is probably exactly that. The standard way of mounting directories on the host is by using `vboxfs` [which does not have read caching](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/7749).

Since this is not going to be changed soon (as it seems) you're better of [using NFS](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/nfs.html) by setting the type of the shared folder to `"nfs"`:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # ...

  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "nfs"
end
```

Note however that this only works on UNIX hosts such as Linux and Mac OS X. But since the problem does not exist on Windows, this should not be a problem.

Comment: as a side question, would switching to the VMWare provider change this performance hit?

Comment: I do not know but I think so, yes. The problem here is the implementation of the vboxfs kernel module which just has no caching. Edit: [Yes this would solve the issue](http://mitchellh.com/comparing-filesystem-performance-in-virtual-machines).

Comment: sorry I meant I shaved 1 minute.. but still that's nothing compared to sub-minute times sans vagrant... :(